# What is JPA pessimistic explicit @Lock usecase (and just @Transactional is not an option)?

Tags: java, jpa, pessimistic-locking

I have some knowledge on JPA and DB locks (both optimistic and pessimistic) and transactions, how they works and what guarantees.

> A TransactionRequiredException is thrown if there is no active transaction when lock is called because explicit locking requires an active transaction.

So my questions is: what is the use case when transaction  (@Transactional in JPA case) is not enough and need explicitly use @Lock( LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_*)?

I interested in exact pessimistic lock, and expect a use case like:

> Alice and Bob simultaneously edit page on wikipedia, Alice start to edit a page and locked it..........................and transaction is redundant/not enough/low performance in this case ............................

I don't expect:

1. > Use @Lock when you need just a lock
2. > Use optimistic lock its better
3. > Locking is used to prevent dirty reads (reading data that hasn't been committed) and non-repeatable reads (reading data that gets deleted by another transaction before the one reading is finished).